# Momentics install missing qcc

Tags: compiler-construction, blackberry-10, qcc

I'm setting up a development environment for BB10 (on a Linux host), and have downloaded and installed the latest Momentics 10.2 (beta).

While I can run the qde (dev environment), when I try to compile a sample project I see an error that 'program qcc not found in path'.  And sure enough there is no qcc on my system.  (But gcc is there).

I thought this would/should install as part of the mementics package.  (The BB site makes it sound like one step installation).  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

- You said you installed the IDE but did you download the latest Native SDK from within momentics?

> When you start the the IDE, you can download and install the
>   BlackBerry 10 Native SDK from within the IDE. The IDE provides a
>   wizard that helps you select an SDK that matches your device.

- Make sure you build the project before deploying. (e.g. press the blue hammer button, before pressing the green play button)

Comment: I think that's the problem.  How do I install the Native SDK from within the IDE?  I've been through PREFERENCES but can't find it...

Comment: Try Help>Check for updates - (not 100% sure as I'm not using a linux machine) - let me know if that works.

Comment: check out my answer - it says where you can find it

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the SDK containing the build tools comes with the Momentics IDE download. You can check that you've got the right SDK installed by going to `Window->Preferences->Blackberry->API Level` and clicking "Get More" there.

That works on my Linux machine for 10.2 Momentics IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to source the qnxsdp-env.sh/.bat depending on your OS. That should set qcc to be in your environment variables.

On Linux: source /qnx710/qnxsdp-env.sh